# Quarter option in datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to add a dropdown for quarter in datepicker. I have tried some solutions but there is no setting to add quarters. I have only seen options for days, months and year. Anyone help please

Comment: "dropdown for quarter"...?

Comment: These are not settings and are built to show anything you would like. What exactly are you working with?

Comment: @entiendo Yes, similarly as datepicker provides functionality to choose months and years from dropdown. So same I want a dropdown for quarter. please see link for dropdown http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/show-only-month-and-year-in-jquery-ui.html

Comment: @josh please see the link and my upper comment I want similar dropdown for quarters of year. What was wrong in my question. Why this downvotes Sorry ?

Comment: @JoshCox you were here for just downvote my question without a reason. If you have reason tell me. And give me a solution if you have?

Comment: @entiendoNull same for you. Please see the link i send you to see dropdowns for month and year

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the HTML select tag.

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Monthly</option>
  <option value="2">quarterly</option>
  <option value="3">yearly</option>
</select>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UKd4v/1/)

Comment: Thanks Josh. How you did this ? :) I am looking a option in datepicker

Comment: @KulbirSingh I think theres is a misunderstanding. I will be happy to chat with you and try to offer some guidance. Inevitably your question got down voted for a few reasons. A) Don't tell people you have tried several things. Show them what you have tried. B) Your understanding of this field "seems" very poor and is evident from your question. C) Only ask questions after you have searched for your answer extensively. I do understand your frustration and will be happy to help you solve your problem. We all started in your shoes! Dont give up.

Comment: please join chat room : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57925/room-for-kulbir-singh-and-tman

Comment: Please join chat room. I send you link in upper comment

Comment: @KulbirSingh sorry my friend I was busy at work. Feel free to try again.

Comment: Its ok dear. Here is new link for chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57982/room-for-kulbir-singh-and-josh-cox

Comment: @KulbirSingh It appears I have missed you again! Im in the office M-F 9-3 EST

Comment: Yea bro I see. No probs when you got free please invite me